# Determining which thread got the synchronized key

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I am learning how to work with threads and I ran into this question that with a given code I need to say what whether a certain thread will or will not be able to access a certain function.
Here is the code :

```
public class InsideClass{}

public class SyncClass{
    private InsideClass in1;
    private InsideClass in2;

public SyncClass(InsideClass i, InsideClass i2){ in1 = i; in2 = i2; }

public synchronized void func1() { System.out.println("in func1"); }

public void func2() { synchronized(in1) { System.out.println("in func2"); }}

public static synchronized void func3() { System.out.println("in func3"); }

public void func4() { synchronized(in2) { System.out.println("in func4"); }}

public synchronized void func5() {
    synchronized(in1) {
        synchronized(in2){ System.out.println("in func5"); }}
}}

public class MyThread extends Thread{
    private SyncClass sc;

    public MyThread(SyncClass s) {
        sc = s;
    }

    public void run(){
        sc.func1();
        sc.func2();
        SyncClass.func3();
        sc.func4();
        sc.func5();
       }
    }

public class Sys {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InsideClass in1 = new InsideClass();
        InsideClass in2= new InsideClass();
        SyncClass s1 = new SyncClass(in1,in2);
        SyncClass s2 = new SyncClass(in2,in1);
        MyThread t1 = new MyThread(s1);
        MyThread t2 = new MyThread(s2);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

The question goes like this, assuming that t1 is preforming task(i) (i=1,2,3,4), will t2 be able to preform func(i+1) or will it get blocked? explain.
I wrote the full question just in case it wasn't clear.

1) Assuming that t1 is preforming func1

- a) Will t2 be able to preform func1?
- b) Will t2 be able to preform func2?
- c) Will t2 be able to preform func3?
- d) Will t2 be able to preform func4?

2) Assuming that t1 is preforming func2.

- a) Will t2 be able to preform func2?
- b) Will t2 be able to preform func3?
- c) Will t2 be able to preform func4?

3) Assuming that t1 is preforming func3

- a) Will t2 be able to preform func3?
- b) Will t2 be able to preform func4?

4) Assuming that t1 is preforming func4

- a) Will t2 be able to preform func4?

5) func5 has a unique implementation.

- a) How many different locks are cought by this method? Specify who they are.
- b) What is the problem that comes up at func5? How would you solve this problem?

I'm not looking for answers to all these questions (even though it would be nice just in case) , but I would like to get an explanation of what is the meaning of an object (in this example in1/in2) inside a synchronized block, when 2 other object are initialized with these objects (s1,s2). If t1 is preforming func1 which is synchronized, how does that effect the attempt to preform func2? (how does the fact that s1 and s2 were initialized with the same objects inflect this issue).

I hope my question was clear enough. Thanks!

Comment: Please correct the posted code.  It is full of errors.

Comment: Code fixed @NormR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `synchronized` statement *acquires* the *intrinsic lock* of the given object, then performs its body, and then *releases* the lock.

```
Object lock = new Object();
synchronized(lock) {
    ...body...
}
```

The Java Runtime Environment (JRE) will never allow two threads to acquire the intrinsic lock of the same object at the same time.  If one thread acquires the lock, then the second thread to attempt it will be *blocked* until the first thread releases the lock.

It's important to know that the lock will be released no matter how the thread exits the `...body...`.  It doesn't matter whether it `return`s, whether it `break`s, whether it simply runs off the end, or whether it throws an exception.  The lock will be released in any case.

---

There's a shortcut way to write a member function whose entire body is synchronized.

This:

```
class MyClass {
    synchronized void foobar(...args...) { ...body... }
}
```

Means exactly the same as this:

```
class MyClass {
    void foobar(...args...) {
        synchronized(this) { ...body... }
    }
}
```

And the same goes for a `synchronized static` function, except that it synchronizes on the class object instead.

This:

```
class MyClass {
    synchronized static void foobar(...args...) { ...body... }
}
```

Means exactly the same as this:

```
class MyClass {
    static void foobar(...args...) {
        synchronized(MyClass.class) { ...body... }
    }
}
```

---

It's important to remember the difference between a variable and an object.  Two threads *can* enter a `synchronized(foo){...}` block at the same time if the variable `foo` refers to two different objects in the two different contexts.  (Think carefully about your `in1` and `in2` member variables!)  Likewise, two different threads can call the same `synchronized` member function at the same time if the two threads are operating on different objects.  (Your example has two different instances of `SyncClass`!)

Comment: First, thanks for the answer! I just want to make sure I got this straight. `synchronized(in1)` actually means that `in1` took the lock, it is referred to the class field `in1` and has nothing to do with the arguments sent to the `SyncClass` c'tor. If that is correct, it means that the only way that one thread would not be able to access a wanted func is if there would of been another lock on `in1`. Did I get this right? @james

Comment: @RanAB , `in1` is a _variable_.  A `synchronized(in1)` statment does not operate on the variable: it operates on the _object_ to which the variable refers.  Your main program constructs two new `InsideClass` objects, and then it passes _references_ to those objects into the construction of two new `SyncClass` objects.  When the `SyncClass` methods synchronize on `in1` or `in2`, it's not the names of the variables that matter, it's the identities of the objects to which the variables refer.  Two threads can not synchronize on the same _object_ at the same time.

Comment: @RanAB P.S., My complements to your teacher.  This is the first really good homework assigment I've seen in a long time.

Comment: This is a bit confusing but I think I got it, if t1 is operating func1, `synchronized(in1)` meant that s1 actually gets the lock, which means that t2 can access func2 with no interference and `synchronized(in2)` will give s2 the lock for that specific func. Is that right ? B.T.W it's not a homework assignment, but yea our teacher gives us good exercise indeed! @james

Answer (score 0):

The code as stands does not compile.

func5 has three open brackets followed and three close brackets

There is no close bracket to then close the class.

If you have a compiler please compile the code and post again.

Comment: Code compiles... I didn't check if it does before posting because I figured that it has nothing to do with the question itself. Running the program will not give me an answer...@PaulGallagher

Comment: Thanks RanAB  I'd edit the code so it compiles otherwise more than like people on here won't answer.                                                                                                                  

public synchronized void func5() {
    synchronized(in1) {
        synchronized(in2){ System.out.println("in func5"); }}
}
}

Comment: Noted. @PaulGallagher